# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError while doing assertEquals on String[]

Tags: java, junit, assert

I have the following class which returns a list of strings.

```
public static String[] parseLinks(String text) {
    String[] result = new String[] {"",""};
            return result;
    }
```

But when I do an assertEquals on the result,

```
    assertEquals(new String[]{"",""}, parseLinks(""));
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected: <[Ljava.lang.String;@2352544e> but was:<[Ljava.lang.String;@721cdeff>
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:329)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:78)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:86)
at junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals(TestCase.java:253)
```

How do I go about fixing this? Please let me know if there is any other additional information that I have to provide.

Comment: Don't confuse lists with arrays, they're two different things. You're returning an *array* of strings there, not a list of strings. I know the difference might seem small but when speaking in technical terms it makes a big difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're comparing two different Array objects. You can use `assertArrayEquals` to compare arrays instead.

Comment: +1 ([Docs here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29))